# Python. В файл выводится только около 400 значений

Tags: python, файловый-ввод-вывод

Провожу запись в блокнотовский тхт файл, но почему-то из 1000 значений записывает 396-399
`print(len(data1))` выдаёт как раз 1000 значений, но такое чувство, будто тхт не хочет становиться больше 8 килобайт. Места на диске, конечно, хватает.

```
mean = 0
std = 1 
num_samples = 1000
data1 = np.random.normal(mean, std, size=num_samples)
f = open('out.txt', "+w")
print(len(data1))
for i in range(1000):
    x=data1[i]
    f.write(str(x)+'\n')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Создайте временный массив, и потом в него записывайте файлы. После чего с помощью цикла запишите все полученные числа

Для примера я использовал библиотеку **random** модуль **randit**

```
from random import randint

b = []
k = 0
while k < 1000:    #задаете сколько вам нужно чисел
    c = randint(100, 1000)    #рандомное число от 100 до 1000
    b.append(c)
    k+=1
with open('num.txt', 'w+') as s:    #автоматически открывает и закрывает файл
    for i in range(len(b)):
        a = s.write(f'{str(b[i])}\n')
```

После запуска у меня сохранилось ровно 1000 строк рандомных чисел

Comment: а зачем вы записываете по одному элементу, когда проще и лучше записать весь список за одно действие?

Comment: @Эникейщик Я так привык писать, д и не прям хорошо владею языком, поэтому выкручиваюсь как могу. Но по мере изучения языка улучшаю знания кода

Answer (score 0):

Файловая система не успевает обрабатывать такое бешеное количество запросов за единицу времени. Сохраняй в переменную и потом запиши один раз:

```
s  = ""
for i in range(1000):
    x=data1[i]
    s = s + str(x)+'\n'

f.write(s)
f.close()
```

И не забывай закрывать файл. А еще лучше работай с файлами через with..., тогда они будут закрывать автоматически.